# Is there a non trivial function whose nth derivative is always 0 at x?

Tags: calculus

The function $f=0$ is $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and verify that there is a number $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such as $f^{n)} (x) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, where $f^{n)}$ is the nth derivative of $f$.

Is there a non trivial function $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ with the same property?

Comment: As the answers show, the answer is yes, and these functions are famous because they show the notions of "smooth" ($C^\infty$) and "analytic" are not the same for real-valued functions.

Comment: to understand these functions, you have to extend them to $x \in \mathbb{C}$, and they'll have an essential singularity at $0$ : $f^{(n)}(0)$ exists only in the real sense, but in the complex sense $\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(ah)-f(0)}{a h}$ will depend on $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and in general will diverge except for certain values of $a$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yes, there is.](http://www.macalester.edu/aratra/chapt2/chapt2_6c.html) Take $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x) = \begin{cases}e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} &\text{ if } x\neq 0\\ 0 &\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$ Then $f$ is smooth, and at $0$ all derivatives are zero.

Answer (score 2):

Take:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}|x|^{1/|x|},&x\ne0\\0,&x=0\end{cases}$$
Note that, for any $N$, it satisfies $0\le f(x)\le|x|^N$ when $x$ is small enough.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how hard is it to prove smoothness (and that the derivatives cancel at $0$) for this one? (absolute values tend me make me fear the worst.)

Comment: Well, it's the same as proving that the right-hand derivatives of $x^{1/x}$ are all $0$. (Although, technically, I don't actually know for sure that it satisfies the criteria because I haven't actually proven it.)

Comment: I reckon one can easily show it by induction (considering wlog only the right-limit), showing first that $f^{(n)}(x)$ is of the form $\frac{f(x)}{p_n(x,\ln x)}$ for some 2-variate polynomial $p_n$, and then showing that for any such polynomial the limit when $x\to 0^+$ is 0.

Comment: @ClementC. I was hoping that _every_ function from $\Bbb R_{\ge0}$ to $\Bbb R_{\ge0}$ that satisfies $f(x)\le x^n$ for small enough $x$ satisfies $f^{(n-1)}(0)=0$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You mean, satisfying this for all $n$? (i.e., convergence "inverse superpolynomial"?)

Comment: @ClementC. For fixed $n$… but I think it's false anyways EDIT: Wait, I'm not so sure.

Comment: I think something based on $\sin^2\frac{1}{x} e^{-1/x^2}$ may be a counterexample (from the heuristic argument "$\sin\frac{1}{x}$ is messy").

Comment: @ClementC. Well, remember that $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)$ need not exist even when $f'(0)$ does. I think that $\sin(1/x)$ stuff can only cause that limit to break.

Comment: But in that case, we want $f$ smooth, right? (or is it off the track of the OP's question -- i.e., a valid question of its own, where we lose smoothness of $f$ but want to (dis)prove your statement from 4 comments above). Still need $f$ to be differentiable $n-1$ times at $0$, though, so at least ${\cal C}^{n-2}$ in a neighborhood.

Comment: For instance, $f(x) = x^3 \sin(1/x)^2$ satisfies $0 \leq f(x) \leq x^3$, and $f^\prime$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ with $f^\prime(0)=0$. But I don't think $f^\prime$ it is differentiable at $0$ (may have messed up my computations).

Comment: @ClementC. Oh, yeah, you're right. Back to square one? (Or, maybe we could add the condition that each derivative is monotonic… but then we'd have to prove that our function satisfies that.)